# How to make all links in a column with different sizes of text the same size as the row in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, rows

I'm writing a website and want to make a column of links that act like buttons (is a block shape, when you hover over and click it changes color, etc.). My code currently looks like this:

```js
function search() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("input");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
html {
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(img/background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

#title {
  background-color: brown;
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 85%;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 800%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 200%;
  color: white
}

.dropdown {
  width: 34%;
  margin-left: 32%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  width: 20%;
  color: white;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
}

.dropdown a:active,
.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: brown;
}

#input {
  width: 98%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <h1 id="title">My stuff</h1>
  <h2>To be directed to the correct thing, click on the corresponding item on the menu.</h2>
  <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a project" id="input" onkeyup="search()">
    <a href="projects/something.html">Blank</a><br>
    <a href="">Another Blank</a><br>
    <a href="">Even More Blanks</a><br>
    <a href="">Final Blank</a><br>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</body>
```

I want, when you hover over the different links on the column, for the entire row to change color. Also, I want the entire row to be part of the link (i.e. you can click anywhere on the row and it will bring you to whatever the link is linked to.). Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code structure is not very good, so you need to change it. Try to use `ul` inside the `dropdown`. Ofcourse this example is not the best, but it does what you want to achieve.

```css
html {
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(img/background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

#title {
  background-color: brown;
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 85%;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 800%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 200%;
  color: white
}

.dropdown {
  width: 34%;
  margin-left: 32%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.dropdown ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  display:block;
  color: white;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
}

.dropdown a:active,
.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: brown;
}

#input {
  width: 98%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <h1 id="title">My stuff</h1>
  <h2>To be directed to the correct thing, click on the corresponding item on the menu.</h2>
  <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a project" id="input" onkeyup="search()">
    <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="projects/something.html">Blank</a><br>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="">Another Blank</a><br>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="">Even More Blanks</a><br>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="">Final Blank</a><br>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
   
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</body>
```

Comment: I didn't think of that! Thanks!

Comment: "Your code structure is not very good, so you need to change it"...….. why or why not? Simply saying that and not providing any details doesn't help anyone learn.